# Plot the deformed shape using python,

Tags: python

how can i use paython to Plot the deformed shape using the nodal solutions (from part b) with the Hermite cubic interpolation functions in the same graph.
when i have solution for b:
[image]

Plot the deformed shape with the Hermite cubic interpolation functions in the same graph. python

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.CubicHermiteSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicHermiteSpline.html) to interpolate values at any desired points between the fixed and free end of the beam.

So to plot your values you can interpolate over your desired positions and compute the corresponding deflections

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicHermiteSpline

L = 10  # beam length
x_computed = [0, L]  # position along beam
v_computed = [0, -0.025]  # displacements
theta_computed = [0, -0.0033]  # rotations

x_new = np.linspace(0, L, 100)  # 100 steps between 0 and beam length
spline = CubicHermiteSpline(x_computed, v_computed, theta_computed)
v_new = spline(x_new)
plt.plot(x_new, v_new)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]